# Customized storage account(s) for Azurite on local windows with VS not working

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, azurite

I have a similar issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749632/customized-storage-account-for-azurite-on-docker-compose), but this is running Azurite on windows with VS against an Azure Function.

I am trying to follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#custom-storage-accounts-and-keys)

Azurite is being initiated by VS through this setting in local.settings.json in the Azure Functions project:

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
```

I have set the environment variables (also tried without quotation marks):

[image: cmdscreenshot]

My connection string is like this:

```
"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=imageaccount;AccountKey=SU1BR0VfQkxPQl9TVE9SQUdFX1VSTA==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/imageaccount;"
```

My BlobContainerClient seems set up to go:
[image]

but calling

```
 await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

throws an exception telling me it is an *"Invalid storage account"*?

**Further info:**

- per 26/06 - 2023
- Latest version of VS 17.6.4
- Azurite version installed by VS: 3.22.0 (Latest version is 3.24.0 ?)

Disabling Azurite startup in VS and running azurite from the console produces another exception with this message:

*"The API version 2022-11-02 is not supported by Azurite. Please upgrade Azurite to latest version and retry. If you are using Azurite in Visual Studio, please check you have installed latest Visual Studio patch. Azurite command line parameter "--skipApiVersionCheck" or Visual Studio Code configuration "Skip Api Version Check" can skip this error. "*

Running from console with the proposed --skipApiVersionCheck I am back to the original exception.

Setting up without the AZURITE_ACCOUNTS environment setting, and with "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" as connection string works

Any clues? Thx..

Comment: What is the Azure Function Version you are using?

Comment: @Harshitha : Azure Functions Core Tools v. 4.0.4895 (x64)

Comment: Are you following the complete document or only `Custom storage accounts and keys` part ?

Comment: @Harshitha  The entire documentation, but the essential part is the one you mention

Comment: I have tried to retrieve the `AZURITE_ACCOUNTS` value, but getting null.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9td99.png)

Comment: Once I close and reopen the commandprompt, Tried to run `SET` the value is not available.

Comment: Try to set the value in Properties=> Debug =>General.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twdMU.png)

Comment: @Harshitha Thx for the effort. Unfortunately adding the entry through launchSettings environmentVariables did not change anything. Pls. note that I have raised an issue on github if you have further inputs. https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues/2018

Comment: Have you tried by setting the environment variable from properties section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254249/discussion-between-noontz-and-harshitha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround was found in [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues/2018)

Currently there is flaws in the documentation and it lacks important details, so to make this work in the questions context, here is the way to go:

- remove this entry `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` from local.settings.json in **ALL** projects to prevent Azurite from starting up in the VS process
- restart VS if Azurite is running (check Output > Service Dependencies)
- start a separate command prompt as Administrator
- navigate to the folder containing Azurite as per the documentation
- run `set AZURITE_ACCOUNTS=account1:key1;account2:key2` *without quotation marks*
- run `azurite --skipApiVersionCheck`

Here is a .bat script for convenience (run as administrator):

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator
set AZURITE_ACCOUNTS=set AZURITE_ACCOUNTS=account1:key1;account2:key2
azurite --skipApiVersionCheck
```

An alternative more "permanent" solution (keep the `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` to start Azurite from VS) is adding the environment variable manually to the windows system variables e.g.

*(for what ever reason, the setting must be set in the **first** startup project when using multiple startup projects in a solution)*

[image]